# What happens at the end of The Thousand year Peaceful - Reign and why is satan released onto the world again?

Tags: judgement

What the purpose is for Satan being released onto the Earth.

Comment: Hello Daniel! As it stands, your question is opinion based. Try rewording your question to ask about a specific denominations view on the end times, or ask for a denominations survey on all the different denominations view.

Comment: The question is, what is the purpose of Satan being released on the world again and what do the different denominations believe the reason for this is?

Comment: This site allows overview questions.  You can edit your question to state that you want an overview.  Overview answers are a bit more difficult to write since each answer should give a sourced response from multiple denominations.  I find it better to ask the question of a specific denomination. You can ask the same question numerous times changing only the denominational scope.

Comment: A JW answer might be based on this source https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1965448?q=abyss&p=par#h=8

Comment: Satan tempted Adam & Eve in the old paradise and sucseed because they have not eaten the fruit of the Tree of Life or the eucharist. In the New Paradise, the New Adam & Eve are living a Eucharistic Life for 1k years, and Satan will be allowed to tempt them again,, but this time, since they were transformed by eucharistic life, Satan will miserably fail in tempting them. And Satan will be humiliated, he no longer have power to tempt the New Adam & New Eve, and will go down to hell voluntarily into its abyss,

Comment: The most comprehensive explanation of this particular aspect ( and the whole entirety) of the book of Revelation is '_The Revelation of Jesus Christ_' by John Metcalfe (in about 700 pages) which covers the variety of interpretations of the book, then focusses on that method which views seven parallel sections layered historically one upon another to cover seven aspects of the Church Age from ascension to return of the Lord Jesus Christ. It is compelling, informative, thoroughly organised and logical, and answers every question I have ever had about the contents.

Comment: Your question has two parts, both of which appear to be answered within "Revelations". If you are asking for conjectures about what happens long after Satan is cast into the "Lake of Fire", please change your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Revelation 20:7-10: “When the thousand years are over, Satan will be released from his prison and will go out to deceive the nations in the four corners of the earth—Gog and Magog—to gather them for battle. In number they are like the sand on the seashore. They marched across the breadth of the earth and surrounded the camp of God’s people, the city he loves. But fire came down from heaven and devoured them. And the devil, who deceived them, was thrown into the lake of burning sulfur, where the beast and the false prophet had been thrown. They will be tormented day and night for ever and ever.”

Opinions vary depending on what interpretation is given to Revelation, whether it is literal or not.  To keep this simple, here is a brief summary from the 1998 book ‘The Revelation of Jesus Christ’ by John Metcalfe.

**Contemporary (Praeterist) Interpretation:**  Everything in Revelation was fulfilled in past history during the first century of the church.

**Historicist Interpretation:** With the exception of the prologue and epilogue, Revelation is a continuing unfolding of the history of the church in the world.  Commences with the apostolic age and continues to unfold to the end of time.

**Futurist interpretation:** Developed as Roman Catholic counter-reformation propaganda which puts everything in the future.  In chapter 4 a secret rapture of the church is proposed.  The prophetic narrative of events from chapter 4 to 22 has nothing to do with the church but is presumed to do with Israel over a future seven year period of tribulation.  A literal thousand years with Israel on earth, and the church suspended in heaven above it; O.T. priesthood, temple, sacrifices reinstituted with the Lord being on earth reigning over Israel and the world.

**Resumptive (Spiritual) interpretation:**  Revelation is applied to all ages of the church and throughout the ages – a vast unfolding of invisible powers and the visible occurrence of events.  Both principles and powers being invisible, they are depicted with graphic imagery in which two opposing forces, in conflict the one with the other, range over the heavens and the earth.  The book repeats the period from the ascension till the judgment seven times over (hence the term ‘resumptive’).  The entire age of the church appears in the spiritual verities which govern it - seven parallel phases of conflict between implacably antagonistic principles.  The sevenfold parallel sections conclude with the last judgment - distinctive aspects of the same struggle.

Here are a few extracts from Metcalfe's book presenting the Resumptive (Spiritual) interpretation:

> Revelation 20:1-2 is a metaphorical picture of the effect of the cross of Christ upon the dragon.  John sees the vision of the descent of the angel.  The purpose of the angel’s descent is quite clear from the verse, namely, to bind the dragon, which is an allegorical description of the Devil – that is, Diabolos – or Satan.  Whilst Satan is bound he is unable to prevent God’s mercy in the gospel going out to the Gentiles (Mark 16:15).

> ***The purpose is for Satan to ‘go out to deceive the nations which are in the four quarters of the earth” (Revelation 20:7-8).***  The Jews were cut off because of unbelief.  And, just as it was with Israel, so it shall be with the Gentiles. God shall blind their eyes, harden their hearts, confuse their understanding, and give them over to be deceived.  Source: The Seventh Opening – Chapters 20 to 22:5 – Part One

Whilst Satan is bound there is still hope for people to come to saving faith in Christ Jesus and what he accomplished 2,000 years ago when he defeated Satan and conquered death itself.  But God has decreed that he will be released for ‘a little season’ prior to the final conflict when Satan attempts to destroy God’s people.

***Signs of the beginning of the little season when Satan is released:***

•   A global turning away from the everlasting gospel.

•   Living as if there were no God, no judgment, and no eternity – a worse state than the previous wickedness while Satan was bound (after Jesus’ death on the cross and his ascension).

•   Apostasy within the whole of Christendom – a falling away of the Church.  2 Thessalonians 2:3-12 says God shall send them a strong delusion, that they should believe a lie: that they all might be damned who believe not the truth, but had pleasure in unrighteousness.

We are even now living in that ‘little season’.  Hence the warning in Revelation chapter 20: it is to alert us to the imminence of the return of Christ Jesus.

Comment: "God will send a strong delusions". Are virus and vaccine example of "strong delusions"? Why? because people embrace it as good, even the Church, eventhough the lies presented are so obvious and its everywhere, and the men behind global vaccination were caught lying numerous times, and this situation will eventually lead to fulfill the prophecy of a Cashless Society under Draconian Rules in Revelation13:16-18. And ofcourse, the emergence of a counterfeit church for catholics who are antivaxxers and anti Novus Ordo are now visible.

Comment: @jongricafort - Yes, there is evidence authorities have mislead the public regarding Covid-19 issues. However, I think the apostasy and the delusion whereby people refuse to repent and curse God instead (Rev. 16:9, 11, 21) has to do with rejecting God's sovereign authority and the power of the cross. Instead, people "take pleasure in unrighteousness" and look to humanity, to science, as their only saviour. The invisible powers at work are depicted with graphic imagery throughout the Revelation. It's much more than a cashless society or opposing vaccinations. It's about faith in God and Christ.